# useradd doesn't allow the user to log on

Tags: bash, perl, administration

On an Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS the following command:

```
adduser fu
```

and then entering a password `bar` and just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on all other questions, creates a user that allows me to log on and has the following characteristics in `/etc/passwd`:

```
fu:x:1002:1002:,,,:/home/fu:/bin/bash
```

However, doing a:

```
useradd fu --password bar --groups adm,cdrom,sudo,dip,plugdev,lpadmin --shell /bin/bash --create-home
```

creates in `/etc/passwd`

```
fu:x:1002:1002::/home/fu:/bin/bash
```

and *does not allow me to log on* and adding `--user-group` does not help neither...

**As I need `useradd`** (for a docker script) *how do I proceed?*

P.S. I've had a look at `/usr/sbin/adduser` already, but as it's `perl` it's not obvious to me which parameters to add to `adduser` to have the same functionality as `useradd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem #1:

The commas in the user entry in `/etc/passwd` are just field separators for user's informations such as "Full Name", "Room Number", "Work Phone" and "Home Phone", so **I guess** that omitting them is the same as having them with blank fields;

Problem #2:

From the [Trusty `man` page for `useradd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/useradd.8.html):

```
[...]
       -p, --password PASSWORD
           The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to
           disable the password.

           Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or
           encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes.

           You should make sure the password respects the system's password
           policy.
[...]
```

This means that the password expected by `useradd` is an already encrypted password (judging from my test through `SHA-512`): in fact the string passed as an argument to the `-p` option is written as plain text in `/etc/shadow` and passwords read from here upon login are expected to be encrypted.

So the most straightforward solution is to set the password using `passwd` instead:

```
echo -e 'bar\nbar' | passwd fu
```

If you can't use `passwd`, this python command in a subshell as an argument to the `-p` option should do:

```
python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("bar", "$6$'$(< /dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c 32)'")'
```

**Command breakdown**:

`python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("<string>", "$<encryption_type>$<encryption_salt>")'`

<sub>*<string> = string to encrypt; <encryption_type> = encryption type; <encryption_salt> = encryption salt</sub>

Crypts a `<string>` using `<encryption type>` and `<encryption_salt>` using the `crypt()` library call

In this case:

- `<string>` = `bar`, the password to encrypt
- `<encryption_type>` = `6`, `SHA-512`
- `<encryption_salt>` = `< /dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c 32`, random 32 character string

Comment: So a `sudo useradd fu --password 'python print crypt.crypt("bar", "$6$'$(< /dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c 32)'")' --user-group --groups adm,cdrom,sudo,dip,plugdev,lpadmin --comment "fu,,," --shell /bin/bash --create-home` should do the trick in a one-liner? (where the single quotes should be back-ticks)

Comment: @Fabby Not exactly, the python command should be executed in a subshell: `sudo useradd fu --password $(python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("bar", "$6$'$(< /dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c 32)'")') --user-group --groups adm,cdrom,sudo,dip,plugdev,lpadmin --comment "fu,,," --shell /bin/bash --create-home`

Comment: Huh!  Just noticed I only accepted and never upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be working because your password `bar` is not encrypted. The man page for `useradd` states:

> `The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3).`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150882/how-to-automatically-add-user-account-and-password-with-a-bash-script) question on Stack Overflow has a few answers which might help you with your script, as the question asks about adding a user along with a password.

As the accepted answer was not updated on that question based on user comments, I will reproduce the solution here:

```
echo -e "bar\nbar\n" | passwd fu
```

That command will change the password for a user `fu` to `bar`. The user needs to have been created using useradd, of course.

Another solution would be to use `chpasswd`, as the second highest voted answer suggests:

```
echo fu:bar | chpasswd
```

I have tested both of these solutions, and they both work.

**Edited** to remove `adduser` info and indicate which suggestions from linked question actually work.

Comment: The link to the SO article doesn't solve my problem. All the rest is about `adduser`, **which I cannot use**, so if you [edit] your answer and come up  with a solution and test it before answering I will accept and upvote your answer instead of the downvote you've now got.
Alternatively, you can delete your answer as that will automatically reverse the negative reputation points...

Comment: Before your edits, it wasn't clear that you **could not** use `adduser`, only that you needed it (which doesn't necessarily mean you **cannot** use it). Also, fair enough, the accepted answer wasn't updated based on feedback. I have updated my answer to clearly indicate what worked. And yes, I did test these, as I tested them before.

Comment: I only added the bold formatting...  The text was always there...  :P  Upvoted already as much better then before.  **;-)** If it works I'll accept as well...