# How to validate a user's password, with a shell script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, password

I'm making a bash script for the Ubuntu Terminal. I need to verify the user before the code can continue. How do I ask and validate their existing log-in password?

Comment: Why is it necessary to validate password ? Unless your script is using sudo for any admin sort of action, then i would suggest you validate user by checking output of the `id` command

Comment: You'll find the following post helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/611580/how-to-check-the-password-entered-is-a-valid-password-for-this-user

Comment: Crossposting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36668824/3776858

Answer (score 0):

You can use Prompty. It will allow you to prompt the user for their password, and then you can use Prompty's exit code to determine if they entered the correct password or not. If they didn't then stop your script.

#### Installation:

[Applies to Prompty 1.0]

1. Download Prompty from one of the links posted at "http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/612007/prompty/" to your Downloads folder.
2. Install Prompty and it's dependencies:

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /opt/prompty
   sudo unzip "$HOME/Downloads/Prompty 1.0 Stable.zip" -d "/opt/prompty" 
   sudo chown -R root "/opt/prompty"
   sudo chgrp -R root "/opt/prompty"
   sudo chmod -R u=rxX,g=rxX,o=rxX "/opt/prompty"
   sudo apt-get install sed grep coreutils bash
   ```

#### Usage

[Applies to Prompty 1.0]

1. At the beginning of your script, execute Prompty.

   ```
   bash /opt/prompty/prompty-cli --task="1" --useuserpassword="y"
   ```
2. Check to see what the exit code was, and use that to determine if your script should terminate:

   ```
   if [ "$?" -ne "254" ] 
   then 
       exit 0
   fi
   ```
3. Add the rest of your script code.

#### Sources

- "About" file from Prompty 1.0 Stable