# How are password hashes compared?

Tags: password, hash

I was doing an exercise today, which includes creating a new user by manually editing /etc/group ; /etc/shadow ; /etc/passwd

Now, referring to /etc/shadow, I had to create password hashes. I used this perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $pwd = $ARGV[0]
chomp($pwd)
my $salt = join "", (".", "/", 0..9, "A".."Z", "a".."z")[rand 64, rand 64];
print crypt($pwd, $salt)."\n";
```

which obviously generates random results every time.

When I tested the results, I found out that I could only login using the password I used before to create the random hash.

My question is: if a single script gets a single password and outputs different hashes, how is that the login program recognizes the real password?

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/611580/how-to-check-the-password-entered-is-a-valid-password-for-this-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is salt used in the crypt method. The same salt always produces the same crypted password. However, the salt is random and then it seems that the whole crypted password is random.

There is salt stored in the crypted password and it is used when checking the password. Password hashing works only one way. When checking the salt is read from encrypted password and password is crypted. If the crypted password is the same as the one in /etc/shadow, the password is OK.

Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Comment: It is not "password encryption" but "password hashing". The reverse of "encryption" is "decryption" which is not a desirable property for password storage.

Comment: @Lekensteyn You are right.